# PHP Update Cell Data Error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

HeyHeyHey!

I am having this problem, for some reason it won't add the Data to my MYSQL Database and I have no idea why. I looked at a lot of other posts here on StackOverflow, but can't seem to find a post that helps me :)

Here is my code:

```js
<script>
  $('.alert-saved-changes-success2').hide();

  $(".save-tradelink-profile").click(function() {
      $tradelinkvalue = document.getElementById("tradelink").value;

      if ($.trim($('#tradelink').val()) == '') {
          alert('Tradelink can not be blank');
      } else if ($tradelinkvalue.indexOf("https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new") >= 0) {   
          <?php //TRYING TO UPDATE DATA
              $TradelinkValue = $_POST['GetTradelinkValue'];

              mysql_query("UPDATE item-jackpot-users SET tradelink=$TradelinkValue WHERE steam_id=$steamid") or die(mysql_error());
          ?>

         $("#alert-saved-changes-success").slideDown("slow"); 
     } else {
         alert('Tradelink has to be valid');
     }
  });

  $(".logout-button-profile").click(function(){
      window.location.href = "steamauth/logout.php";
  });
</script>
```

It seems like the php tag gets loaded before everything else, since the

```js
$('.alert-saved-changes-success2').hide();
```

doesn't load. It finds the error, and then just killing everything else.

Comment: "It seems like the php tag gets loaded before everything else" - yes, that's how it's working. The only thing (commonly) connecting the javascript executed "within" browser and server-side php are the http requests/repsonses. Only the output of the php script is sent to the browser and when the user interacts with the ui, the php instance serving the html page and/or ajax data is long done and already garbage collected (and maybe re-used for the next request).

Comment: My eyes jumped straight to what was wrong with your SQL statement, but I deleted my answer, you have things mashed together that shouldn't be, and you have errors in your SQL, and your SQL is vulnerable to attacks, I think you should read more about the technologies you're trying to use.

Comment: @ChrisTrudeau Thanks Alot! I think your right, i have to read more up on it :)

Comment: @VolkerK Thanks for the hint! i will look into it

Comment: I hope that didn't sound discouraging, you'll get to a point where it all makes sense, good luck

Answer (score 0):

Respecting the fact that yes, php is performed before your webbrowser receives the js text, you could use a form, that sends your update information into post(like using a form tag), reload the page, and make the page perform the update with your post data. You could also use ajax.

```
<form name="login" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="refer to this file" >
    <div class="form-group">

            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">
                    Username
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input class="pull-right" type="text" name="username" />
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">

            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">
                    Password
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input class="pull-right" type="password" name="password" />
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <div class=" col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-2"> 
                <button type="submit" name="submitbtn" class="btn btn-default pull-right">
                        Sign in
                </button>
            </div>
    </div>
</form>

<?php 

$user = $_POST['username'];
$pwd = $_POST['password'];
//DO SOME SANITIZATION!
//Store $user and $pwd
?>
```

Ofcourse you could include the php part somewhere else in the file, like inside of a script tag.

Comment: Thanks alot! <3 i will check it back :)